# Android Transition of layouts from left and Right

Tags: android, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a requirement that when i call next activity i want to do transitions of layouts.
The current layout should move to the left and next or the new view should move right like in an HDFC Mobile Banking application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapwork.hdfc&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zbmFwd29yay5oZGZjIl0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**res/anim/slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

**res/anim/slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Activity2.java**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use overridePendingTransition to change the transition right after/before calling finish or startActivity.